# ImageButton Neighboring Validation

Tags: android, validation, imagebutton

I  have a 4x4 tile of letters. I wanted to have a validation that only those letters nearest to the tapped/clicked/pressed letter must be clickable and others are set as unclickable. I have my code (see below) for image1. I am having a second thought of how will I enable disabled ImageButton when I tap ImageButton near it.

**Example of set:**

1 | 5 | 9  | 13

2 | 6 | 10 | 14

3 | 7 | 11 | 15

4 | 8 | 12 | 16

If I clicked/pressed 1 then the 2, 5 and 6 are clickable and the rest are not. Then, I'll click 2 and 1, 3, 5, 6 and 7 must be clickable.

**QUESTIONS:**

1. How can I avoid button being clicked again if its already clicked?
2. How can I enable disabled button and avoiding my Q1?

I am using Android Studio.

Code

```js
if (image1.isPressed()) {
            image1.setClickable(false);
            image2.setClickable(true);
            image3.setClickable(false);
            image4.setClickable(false);
            image5.setClickable(true);
            image6.setClickable(true);
            image7.setClickable(false);
            image8.setClickable(false);
            image9.setClickable(false);
            image10.setClickable(false);
            image11.setClickable(false);
            image12.setClickable(false);
            image13.setClickable(false);
            image14.setClickable(false);
            image15.setClickable(false);
            image16.setClickable(false);
        }
```

TIA :)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid writing conditional code. Writing if for each and every image click is a bad practice. So, you can create an arraylist which will always hold the clickable buttons. Based on the clicked button, change this arraylist. Pass this list to a method, which shall enable or disable the clicks for you.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really about ImageButtons, but rather, what algorithm or methodology would you use to determine which regions are clickable, based on the current state of the system.

We need to separate the logic somewhat. On one side you have your View. Let's just put everything related to updating your grid into a black box, say `void updateGrid(List<List< Boolean>> grid)`. Let's maintain a matrix with entries determining whether or not a button is clickable.

Initially all of the buttons are clickable. You're going to get some notification when a button is clicked, say from a callback `void onButtonClick(int i, int j)`, where `i` and `j` give the position of the button. I'm deliberately being vague about this, you'll most likely get an `id`, and need to resolve the `i` and `j` positions yourself. In which case perhaps you'll want to encapsulate the buttonStates and positions in some kind of object - it's up to you.

```java
private <List<List<Boolean>> mGrid;

private static final int GRID_LENGTH = ...;
private static final int GRID_WIDTH = ...;

private static final defaultValue = false;

public void onButtonClick(int i, int j) {
  List<List<Boolean>> newGrid = selectGridRegion(i, j);
  updateGrid(newGrid);
}

private List<List<Boolean>> selectGridRegion(int i, int j) {
  if (!isValidRegion(i, j)) {
    return mGrid;
  }

  ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> grid = makeGrid();
  for (int row = 0; row < GRID_LENGTH; row++) {
    ArrayList<Boolean> gridRow = grid.get(row);
    for (int col = 0; col < GRID_WIDTH; col++) {
      gridRow.set(col, isNeighboringRegion(i, j, row, col));
    }
  }

  return grid;
}

private static boolean isNeighboringRegion(int i, int j, int m, int n) {
  return (Math.abs(i - m) == 1 && Math.abs(j - n) == 1);
}

private static List<List<Boolean>> makeGrid() {
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> grid = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>>();

  for (int i = 0; i < GRID_LENGTH; i++) {
    ArrayList<Boolean> row = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    for (int j = 0; j < GRID_WIDTH; j++) {
      row.add(defaultValue);
    }

    grid.add(row);
  }

  return grid;
}

private static boolean isValidRegion(int i, int j) {
  boolean isValid = false;
  if (0 <= i && i < GRID_LENGTH) {
      if (0 <= j && j < GRID_WIDTH) {
        isValid = true;
      }
  }

  return isValid;
}
```

Now, that's a general approach to modeling the grid. All these method except for `onButtonClick` sound very much like they should be encapsulated in a `Grid` class! You might want to extend `ArrayList`, or something similar.